# Confusion in Excess hole concentration

Tags: current, semiconductors, homework

I have one confusion in the **Millman'S Integrated Electronics 2E**
in the exponential decaying graph its saying that **P'(x)** is the **excess hole concentration** or the injected concentration

[image]

> but in the next page in one example it taking **excess hole density** as **P(X) but not P'(x)** Why it is so ? what i am  missing? can anyone help Please?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're right, but p_o is so much smaller than P(0) regardless that it won't make a big difference in the final result.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sir i also thougt the same but in some other problems i am getting bigger no of p_o where result is effecting ..but this not convincing answer what your are saying.