# NPN Transistor common emitter calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, ltspice, npn, thevenin

I built the following circuit in LTSpice using the default NPN BJT model (beta = 100).

I calculated the Ib to be 115.754uA.
This is how I did the calculation:

> 1. Equivalent voltage at base is:
>      12V * (800/(800+1000+220)) = 4.75V
> 2. Equivalent series input resistance = Equivalent Voltage / Equivalent Current:
>      4.75 / (12v / 1220ohm) = 482.9V
> 3. This turns the input into equivalent circuit like so:
>      [image: Equivalent Circuit]
> 4. Use KVL to solve Q1 (assuming Vbe is 0.8V):
>      4.75 - ib * 482.9 - 0.8 - ie * 330 = 0
>      ie = ib + ic and ic = 100 * ib
>      ie = ib * 101
>      4.75 - 0.8 = ib * (482.9 + 101 * 330)
>      ib = 116.82uA
>      ic = ib * 100 = 11.68mA
> 5. but the simulation shows:
>      ib = 1.3mA and ic = 8.65mA

What is wrong with my calculation?

[image: Original Circuit]

Comment: Your calculated Ic of 11.69 mA would put the collector voltage *way below the base voltage*.  Your assumption of linear operation isn't true.

Comment: Your calculations are correct assuming linear operation, but your transistor is saturated.

Comment: Read this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367267/voltage-divider-bias-bjt-leads-to-a-huge-voltage-drop-across-the-collector-res/367279#367279 It should help.

Comment: Thank you. When in saturation mode, the Vce,sat of the spice NPN is set to 0.05756V, and the Vbe,sat is 836mV. After using these two values, i am able to solve the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assuming Active Mode

The Thevenin equivalent of your base divider is:

$$\begin{align*}V_{\text{TH}}&=V_\text{CC}\cdot \frac{R_5}{R_3+R_4+R_5}\approx 4.7525\:\text{V}\\\\R_{\text{TH}}&=R_5\cdot\frac{R_3+R_4}{R_3+R_4+R_5}\approx 483.17\:\Omega\end{align*}$$

If you assume that the BJT is in active mode (not saturated) then you come up with the approximate value for the base current this way:

$$\begin{align*}I_\text{B}&=\frac{V_{\text{TH}}-V_\text{BE}}{R_{\text{TH}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot R_2}\approx 120\:\mu\text{A}\end{align*}$$

From this, you and work out that the expected voltage drop across the collector resistor would be in excess of \$\beta\cdot R_3\cdot 120\:\mu\text{A}\approx 12 \:\text{V}\$. This, alone, tells you that the circuit is saturated.

***So the assumption for active mode is wrong.***

### Saturated Mode Conclusion

The new circuit, now that you know it is saturated, looks more like this. Using \$V_\text{SAT}=100\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_\text{BE}=700\:\text{mV}\$, for example, it's:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiMK2O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Note that in saturated mode, the collector looks more like a voltage source and not like a current source [as it does when in active mode.])

At this point, use nodal analysis to solve:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{B}}{R_\text{TH}}+I_{V_\text{BE}}&=\frac{V_\text{TH}}{R_\text{TH}}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{C}}{R_1}+I_{V_\text{SAT}}&=\frac{V_\text{CC}}{R_1}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{E}}{R_2}&=I_{V_\text{BE}}+I_{V_\text{SAT}}\\\\
V_\text{B}&=V_\text{E}+V_\text{BE}\\\\
V_\text{C}&=V_\text{E}+V_\text{SAT}\\\\
&\therefore\\\\
V_\text{E}&\approx 3.326\:\text{V}\\\\
V_\text{B}&\approx 4.026\:\text{V}\\\\
V_\text{C}&\approx 3.426\:\text{V}\\\\
\mid\, I_\text{B}\mid=I_{V_\text{BE}}&\approx 1.504\:\text{mA}\\\\
\mid\, I_\text{C}\mid=I_{V_\text{SAT}}&\approx 8.574\:\text{mA}\\\\
\mid\, I_\text{E}\mid=I_{R_2}= \frac{V_\text{E}}{R_2}&\approx 10.078\:\text{mA}
\end{align*}$$

***That's the complete analysis for the circuit.***

### Summary

For small signal BJTs, \$V_\text{BE}=700\:\text{mV}\$ when \$I_\text{C}\approx 1.5-2.0\:\text{mA}\$. Clearly, this collector current is more than that range. So I'd expect about \$26\:\text{mV}\cdot\operatorname{ln}\left(\frac{8.574\:\text{mA}}{1.5\:\text{mA}}\right)\approx 45\:\text{mV}\$ higher, or \$V_\text{BE}\approx 745\:\text{mV}\$. You could go back through the process and come up with a refined quantitative calculation. But the above analysis is already close enough and BJTs vary, anyway. So there's no real need to do more.

(Also note that you are using a default BJT in Spice and I'm using more practical estimates for typical small-signal BJTs.)